# conditional formatting by date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following table in my report

```
Address           SeenDate    

stack street      2015-01-02          
over lane         2016-03-15
flow way          2017-05-12
```

I would like to highlight addresses in green that have got a 'SeenDate' within 12 months, I think this will need to be a rolling 12 months. So from the table above 'flow way' will be highlighted in green.

Comment: Within 12 months of today?

Comment: well it will be from the date the report is ran

Comment: If statement and DateDiff(MONTH,SeenDate,Today()) <= 12 then do you conditions. Might need to mve the dates around I always mess those orders up.

Comment: @Snowlockk  `Datediff` doesn't actually return the number of units that have passed, just the number of unit *boundaries* crossed getting from one date to another.  You can see this in action where the `datediff` of `2016/12/31 23:59:59` and `2017/01/01 00:00:00` will return `1` for `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour` `Minute` *and* `Second`.  Consequently in this type of requirement, you get much more accurate results comparing the date with the date a year ago from today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a conditional on your date value to highlight records that are within 12 months of the report execution date, you can compare the date value with a year ago from today using `iif` in the `Fill` expression of the textbox:

```
=iif(Fields!SeenDate.Value >= Today().AddYears(-1), "Green", "Red")
```

---

Also a note to add that `Today` gives you the date for today and `Now` gives you the date and time of right now, depending on how precise you want to be.